Unable to add user full name in Power APP Patch function. It is getting errro
I am currently using the following patch function, all is working fine. But when I required the user's full name it started getting errors. Below is an example: -
working fine code:-
ForAll(Gallery3.AllItems, Patch('Order Form Data', Defaults('Order Form Data'), {Title: Item, 'Item code': 'Item Code', Discription: Discription, Quantity: Quantity, Date: Today() }));

Code:- Getting Error
ForAll(Gallery3.AllItems, Patch('Order Form Data', Defaults('Order Form Data'), {Title: Item, 'Item code': 'Item Code', Discription: Discription, Quantity: Quantity, Date: Today(), 'Created by': User().FullName }));


you have two 'Item code' in your ForAll function. Once it populates with 'Item code', and once with 'User().FullName'. It can cause the error.

I am so sorry, I have edited my code where I am getting the error, can you please answer now.

@Vipin: the 'Created by' is a read only field, you can't edit it. Anyway, you don't need to edit it, because the PowerApps app runs on behalf of the user, so do the patch function as well. This means, that the 'Created by' field will be populated by the user's data by default. Long story short: you can skip the 'Created by' field from your patch function.
